# CLIGL - A library for command line graphics

Tags: c#, console, graphics

About a year ago I wrote a small library for drawing graphics on the windows command line. I mostly used it for small projects, like a raycaster and a raytracer. I just rediscovered it today, at the time of me writing this question, and decided that it needed a review.

The library is split into six different classes:

- `Interop` - an `internal` class for dealing with command-line related interop functions and structures.
- `RenderingPixel` - stores information (foreground/background color and character) about a "pixel" on the command line.
- `RenderingBuffer` - stores and manages a large array of `RenderingPixels`, as well as providing drawing utilities.
- `RenderingShader` - provides a means to manipulate the pixels of a `RenderingBuffer` after it's been drawn to.
- `RenderingTexture` - stores an array of pixels which can be drawn to a `RenderingBuffer`.
- `RenderingWindow` - responsible for the creation and management of the command line window.

I'm mostly wondering what I can improve in the areas of performance and design, but any other criticisms are welcome.

**Interop.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains various external interop methods and structures 
    /// used to help speed up CLIGL rendering and provide more functionality.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Interop
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a file or open a device.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">The name of the file or device.</param>
        /// <param name="fileAccess">The access to the file or device.</param>
        /// <param name="fileShare">The sharing mode of the file or device.</param>
        /// <param name="securityAttributes">The security attributes of the file or device.</param>
        /// <param name="creationDisposition">The action to take on a file or device that does not exist.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">The file or device attributes.</param>
        /// <param name="template">A valid handle to a template file.</param>
        /// <returns>A handle to a file or device.</returns>
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
            string fileName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
            IntPtr securityAttributes,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
            IntPtr template
        );

        /// <summary>
        /// Write character and color attribute data to a specified area of a
        /// console screen buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hConsoleOutput">A handle to the console screen buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="lpBuffer">The buffer to be written to the screen buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="dwBufferSize">The size of the buffer to be written.</param>
        /// <param name="dwBufferCoord">The upper-left coordinates of the buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="lpWriteRegion">The upper-left and lower-right coordinates of the screen buffer to write to.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the operation was successful.</returns>
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool WriteConsoleOutput(
            SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
            CharInfo[] lpBuffer,
            Coord dwBufferSize,
            Coord dwBufferCoord,
            ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion
        );

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a C++-esque character union, containing a Unicode character
        /// and an ASCII character.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct CharUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public char AsciiChar;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains information about a character to be written to the console, like
        /// the character data and color data.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct CharInfo
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public CharUnion Char;
            [FieldOffset(2)] public short Attributes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a 2D coordinate with components of the type "short".
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Coord
        {
            public short X;
            public short Y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a 2D coordinate with components of the type "int".
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Point
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a small rectangle, with components of the type "short".
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SmallRect
        {
            public short Left;
            public short Top;
            public short Right;
            public short Bottom;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a normal rectangle, with components of the type "int".
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Rect
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

**RenderingPixel.cs**

```
using System;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is intended to be a compact representation of a "pixel"
    /// in CLIGL, which can be used instead of passing around individual characters
    /// and colors.
    /// </summary>
    public struct RenderingPixel
    {
        public static RenderingPixel EmptyPixel = new RenderingPixel(' ', ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Black);
        public static RenderingPixel FullPixel = new RenderingPixel(' ', ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.White);

        public char Character { get; set; }
        public ConsoleColor ForegroundColor { get; set; }
        public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the RenderingPixel class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="character">The character that represents the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="foregroundColor">The foreground color of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="backgroundColor">The background color of the pixel.</param>
        public RenderingPixel(char character, ConsoleColor foregroundColor, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
        {
            this.Character = character;
            this.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
            this.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check to see if two rendering pixels are equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">The first rendering pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="b">The second rendering pixel.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the objects are equal.</returns>
        public static bool operator==(RenderingPixel a, RenderingPixel b)
        {
            if(
                a.Character == b.Character &&
                a.ForegroundColor == b.ForegroundColor &&
                a.BackgroundColor == b.BackgroundColor
            )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check to see if two rendering pixels are not equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">The first rendering pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="b">The second rendering pixel.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether or not the objects are not equal.</returns>
        public static bool operator!=(RenderingPixel a, RenderingPixel b)
        {
            if(
                a.Character == b.Character && 
                a.ForegroundColor == b.ForegroundColor &&
                a.BackgroundColor == b.BackgroundColor
            )
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**RenderingBuffer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a CLIGL render buffer, which is responsible for 
    /// managing what will currently be drawn to the screen.
    /// </summary>
    public class RenderingBuffer
    {
        public int BufferWidth { get; set; }
        public int BufferHeight { get; set; }
        public int BufferSize { get; set; }
        public RenderingPixel[] PixelBuffer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the RenderingBuffer class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bufferWidth">The width of the text and color buffers.</param>
        /// <param name="bufferHeight">The height of the text and color buffers.</param>
        public RenderingBuffer(int bufferWidth, int bufferHeight)
        {
            this.BufferWidth = bufferWidth;
            this.BufferHeight = bufferHeight;
            this.BufferSize = this.BufferWidth * this.BufferHeight;

            this.PixelBuffer = new RenderingPixel[this.BufferSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < this.BufferSize - 1; i++)
            {
                this.PixelBuffer[i] = RenderingPixel.EmptyPixel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a 1-dimensional index to a 2-dimensional index in the form 
        /// of a int array with two values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index to convert/</param>
        /// <returns>A 2-dimensional index.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public int[] Convert1DIndexTo2DIndex(int index)
        {
            int x = index % this.BufferWidth;
            int y = index / this.BufferWidth;
            return new int[] { x, y };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a 2-dimensional index to a 1-dimensional index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate.</param>
        /// <returns>A 1-dimensional index.</returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public int Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + (y * this.BufferWidth);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply a shader to the current rendering buffer, which may change the contents
        /// of the buffer, changing how the buffer looks when it is rendered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="renderingShader">The shader to apply.</param>
        public void ApplyShader(RenderingShader renderingShader)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.BufferSize - 1; i++)
            {
                int[] pixelPosition = this.Convert1DIndexTo2DIndex(i);
                this.PixelBuffer[i] = renderingShader.Execute(pixelPosition[0], pixelPosition[1], this.PixelBuffer[i]);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear the current active pixel buffer with a clear character, a
        /// foreground clear color and a background clear color.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clearPixel">The pixel to clear the pixel buffer with.</param>
        public void ClearPixelBuffer(RenderingPixel clearPixel)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.BufferSize - 1; i++)
            {
                this.PixelBuffer[i] = clearPixel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a pixel into the current pixel buffer using a 1D index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="fillPixel">The pixel to fill the index with.</param>
        public void SetPixel(int index, RenderingPixel fillPixel)
        {
            if(index < this.BufferSize)
            {
                this.PixelBuffer[index] = fillPixel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a pixel into the current pixel buffer using a 2D index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="fillPixel">The pixel to fill the coordinates with.</param>
        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, RenderingPixel fillPixel)
        {
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < this.BufferWidth && y < this.BufferHeight)
            {
                int pixelIndex = this.Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(x, y);
                this.PixelBuffer[pixelIndex] = fillPixel;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a rectangle of pixels into the current pixel buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the rectangle.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the rectangle.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the rectangle.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The height of the rectangle.</param>
        /// <param name="fillPixel">The pixel to fill the rectangle with.</param>
        public void SetRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, RenderingPixel fillPixel)
        {
            for(int xi = x; xi < x + width; xi++)
            {
                for(int yi = y; yi < y + height; yi++)
                {
                    this.SetPixel(xi, yi, fillPixel);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a texture into the current pixel buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the texture.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the texture.</param>
        /// <param name="texture">The texture to set.</param>
        public void SetTexture(int x, int y, RenderingTexture texture)
        {
            for(int xi = 0; xi < texture.Width; xi++)
            {
                for(int yi = 0; yi < texture.Height; yi++)
                {
                    this.SetPixel(x + xi, y + yi, texture.RenderingPixels[xi, yi]);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a string into the current pixel buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x position of the string.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y position of the string.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The text to set.</param>
        /// <param name="foregroundColor">The foreground color of the string.</param>
        /// <param name="backgroundColor">The background color of the string.</param>
        public void SetString(int x, int y, string text, ConsoleColor foregroundColor, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                this.SetPixel(x + i, y, new RenderingPixel(text[i], foregroundColor, backgroundColor));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write the pixel buffer to the C# command-line interface, which will
        /// produce specific output based on the contents of the pixel buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="consoleHandle">The handle to the current console window.</param>
        public void Render(SafeFileHandle consoleHandle)
        {
            Interop.CharInfo[] characterBuffer = new Interop.CharInfo[this.BufferWidth * this.BufferHeight];
            Interop.SmallRect windowRectangle = new Interop.SmallRect()
            {
                Left = 0,
                Top = 0,
                Right = (short)this.BufferWidth,
                Bottom = (short)this.BufferHeight
            };

            for(int i = 0; i < characterBuffer.Length; i++)
            {
                characterBuffer[i].Attributes = (byte)((byte)this.PixelBuffer[i].ForegroundColor | ((byte)this.PixelBuffer[i].BackgroundColor << 4));
                characterBuffer[i].Char.AsciiChar = this.PixelBuffer[i].Character;
            }

            Interop.WriteConsoleOutput(
                consoleHandle,
                characterBuffer,
                new Interop.Coord() { X = (short)this.BufferWidth, Y = (short)this.BufferHeight },
                new Interop.Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 },
                ref windowRectangle
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**RenderingShader.cs**

```
using System;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a CLIGL shader. A shader in CLIGL is essentially
    /// an anonymous function that is applied to every pixel in a rendering buffer,
    /// or every pixel in a rendering buffer that is inside the specified region.
    /// </summary>
    public class RenderingShader
    {
        public int RegionX { get; set; }
        public int RegionY { get; set; }
        public int RegionWidth { get; set; }
        public int RegionHeight { get; set; }
        public Func<int, int, RenderingPixel, RenderingPixel> Function { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the RenderingShaderClass.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="regionX">The x coordinate of the region the shader affects.</param>
        /// <param name="regionY">The y coordinate of the region the shader affects.</param>
        /// <param name="regionWidth">The width of the region the shader affects.</param>
        /// <param name="regionHeight">The height of the region the shader affects.</param>
        /// <param name="function">The shader's function.</param>
        public RenderingShader(int regionX, int regionY, int regionWidth, int regionHeight, Func<int, int, RenderingPixel, RenderingPixel> function)
        {
            this.RegionX = regionX;
            this.RegionY = regionY;
            this.RegionWidth = regionWidth;
            this.RegionHeight = regionHeight;
            this.Function = function;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute the shader, and return an output pixel based on what the shader
        /// does to, and with the inputs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate the shader is executing at.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate the shader is executing at.</param>
        /// <param name="inputPixel">The input pixel at the x and y coordinates.</param>
        /// <returns>An output pixel, or the input pixel, if the input pixel is out of bounds.</returns>
        public RenderingPixel Execute(int x, int y, RenderingPixel inputPixel)
        {
            if(x >= this.RegionX && x <= this.RegionX + this.RegionWidth && y >= this.RegionY && y <= this.RegionY + this.RegionHeight)
            {
                return this.Function(x, y, inputPixel);
            }
            else
            {
                return inputPixel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RenderingTexture.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is intended to represented a rendering texture, which is a
    /// 2-dimensional array of Pixel objects.
    /// </summary>
    public class RenderingTexture
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public RenderingPixel[,] RenderingPixels { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the RenderingTexture class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the rendering texture.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The height of the rendering texture.</param>
        public RenderingTexture(int width, int height)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.RenderingPixels = new RenderingPixel[this.Width, this.Height];

            for(int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
                {
                    this.RenderingPixels[x, y] = RenderingPixel.EmptyPixel;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply a shader to the current rendering texture, which may change the contents
        /// of the texture, changing how the texture looks when it is rendered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="renderingShader">The shader to apply.</param>
        public void ApplyShader(RenderingShader renderingShader)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
                {
                    this.RenderingPixels[x, y] = renderingShader.Execute(x, y, this.RenderingPixels[x, y]);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a pixel into the texture at the specified coordinates.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate of the pixel.</param>
        /// <param name="pixel">The pixel to set.</param>
        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, RenderingPixel pixel)
        {
            if(x >= 0 && x < this.Width && y >= 0 && y < this.Height)
            {
                this.RenderingPixels[x, y] = pixel;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("The provided coordinates '({0}, {1})' are out of range.", x, y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RenderingWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace CLIGL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a CLIGL "window", which contains the various components
    /// required for window rendering and is responsible for managing and updating them.
    /// </summary>
    public class RenderingWindow
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public SafeFileHandle ConsoleHandle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Window class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the window.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The height of the window.</param>
        public RenderingWindow(string title, int width, int height)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;

            Console.Title = this.Title;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

            Console.SetWindowSize(this.Width, this.Height);
            Console.SetBufferSize(this.Width, this.Height);

            this.ConsoleHandle = Interop.CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if(this.ConsoleHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Creating the console window handle failed.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render the window. This function will render the provided rendering buffer
        /// to the console window output. If the dimensions of the provided rendering
        /// buffer do not match the dimensions of the window, then an error is thrown.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="renderingBuffer">The rendering buffer to render.</param>
        public void Render(RenderingBuffer renderingBuffer)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetWindowSize(this.Width, this.Height);
                Console.SetBufferSize(this.Width, this.Height);

                if(renderingBuffer.BufferWidth == this.Width && renderingBuffer.BufferHeight == this.Height)
                {
                    renderingBuffer.Render(this.ConsoleHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("The dimensions of the provided rendering buffer do not match the dimensions of the window.");
                }
            }
            catch(IOException) { }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

**Examples**

The following two videos are very simple, small examples of what one can do with CLIGL. However, they are only the bare minimum. Anything from a 2D game to a full-blown 3D renderer is theoretically possible.

[image]

[image]

Finally, for those who are interested, the GitHub repository for CLIGL can be found [here](https://github.com/Ethan-Bierlein/CLIGL). For those who would like to see example usage, see [here](https://gist.github.com/Ethan-Bierlein/52b13707d6f766e3fc95169e9144a5f7).

Comment: These GIFs are killing my browsers. The CPU usage skyrockets to 100%

Comment: I have a question about the naming... by pixel do you mean a single char in a console? Does it really require system calls? How about the _standard_ console APIs that .Net provides? Wouldn't they work?

Comment: @t3chb0t Yes. A 'pixel' stores three components, the character, a foreground color and a background color. As for the system calls - technically, no. But the standard console utilities are much too slow when it comes to writing large character buffers to the console.

Comment: @t3chb0t The first iteration of this project did not take advantage of system calls, but rather used the console utilities provided. I switched to system calls for the reasons I listed above.

Comment: Good to know but this is interesting because the console uses system calls too (I just looked a the source code) although it does a lot of additional stuff that probably adds some overhead.

Comment: @t3chb0t My original iteration was naively implemented and simply iterated over each buffer, using `Console.Write`. I wrote it this way because there aren't any methods within `Console` that allow the writing of an entire buffer to the console, which is significantly faster. I'm 99% sure this is why using system calls is more performant.

Comment: Could you add an example how to run it so that the console produces some psychadelic stuff? ;-) I've copied everything but I'm not sure what to call. I couldn't find an example in your repo either... or I was looking in the wrong place...

Comment: @t3chb0t Definitely! I can't remember where I placed the code for those two gifs, but I can certainly make a 'tutorial' of sorts. Give me a bit and I should have it up. :)

Comment: @t3chb0t Took me a bit to put it together, but you can find a tutorial file [here](https://gist.github.com/Ethan-Bierlein/52b13707d6f766e3fc95169e9144a5f7), as well as instructions on how to set up CLIGL. It should cover all the features. :)

Comment: Wow, this is really good explained and it's running! ;-D

Comment: @t3chb0t Awesome! If you have any other questions, I'd be glad to help. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### RenderingPixel

Well, a `struct` should be immutable if possible. For the `RenderingPixel` struct this is possible by making the fields `EmptyPixel` and `FullPixel` readonly and the properties `Character`, `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` private settable. Not doing so will asking for the sense of the constructor at all.

The `==` operator can be sanitized to

```
public static bool operator ==(RenderingPixel a, RenderingPixel b)
{
    return a.Character == b.Character &&
           a.ForegroundColor == b.ForegroundColor &&
           a.BackgroundColor == b.BackgroundColor;
}
```

which is clearer.

The `!=` operator could just look like so

```
public static bool operator !=(RenderingPixel a, RenderingPixel b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

#### RenderingBuffer

The lines

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < this.BufferSize - 1; i++)
> {
>     this.PixelBuffer[i] = RenderingPixel.EmptyPixel;
> }
> ```

inside the constrcutor should be changed to

```
ClearPixelBuffer(RenderingPixel.EmptyPixel);
```

to remove the small code duplication.

Calling `SetPixel` for `index < 0` will blow in your face.

---

#### General

- If you don't need to change a property from the outside, make it `private set`.
- Always validate method parameters of `public` methods if they likely can throw an exception. Better throw the exception yourself so you won't expose implementation details.
- If validating method parameters like you did in the `RenderingTexture.SetPixel()` method you should throw early instead of at the end of the method.

Comment: CA1060: just a small (maybe pedantic) addition: I'd also split `Interop` into usual class `NativeMethods` (`UnsafeNativeMethods` and `SafeNativeMethods`? I guess we don't need it)