# Generating Infinite Procedural Terrain Using Command-Line Graphics

Tags: c#, game, console, simulation

Continuing my trend of (ab)using the Windows command-line interface to do fancy graphics-related things with my command-line-graphics library, [CLIGL](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166712/cligl-a-library-for-command-line-graphics), I've created an infinite procedural terrain generator, capable of generating coherent fractal noise to an appreciable distance.

The basic structure of the project is as follows:

- `EntryPoint`: Relatively self-explanatory. This class contains the actual entry point for the program; it performs the initialization of a CLIGL `RenderingWindow` and `RenderingBuffer`, and creates an instance of the `ChunkManager` class.
- `Position`: A helper class used to store a two-dimensional position; it implements a `Transform()` function and overrides `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.
- `Chunk`: responsible for generating, managing, and rendering a set of chunk data stored in a `RenderingPixel[,]` array; it also contains several private helper methods used in the process of terrain generation, as well as a collection of constants used for fractal noise generation and terrain detail generation.
- `ChunkManager`: responsible for loading, maintaining, and rendering a dictionary of chunks, as well as moving the viewport; it will also generate a seed used for individual chunk generation. It will add chunks to the dictionary if necessary (i.e., if there *should* be a chunk loaded within the current view range, but there isn't) and will delete chunks if necessary (i.e., if there is a chunk loaded, but is outside the current view range); it should be noted that the processes of chunk addition and deletion will only occur if the position of the chunk manager (the viewport) itself is changing.

A brief outline of the specific algorithm used to generate noise values:

1. Fractal noise values \$a\$ and \$b\$ are generated with specific base frequencies \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$, respectively (also referred to as "noise scale"; cf. `NOISE_SCALE_A` and `NOISE_SCALE_B`).
2. A third noise value, \$t\$, is generated with a different base frequency (again, also referred to as "noise scale"; cf. `NOISE_SCALE_T`).
3. Linear interpolation is then performed between \$a\$ and \$b\$ using \$\frac{t + 1.0}{2.0}\$ as the time value (note: the noise library I am using generates simplex noise in the range \$-1.0 \rightarrow 1.0\$, hence the adjustment of \$t\$).
4. Basic terrain detail (background color) is then generated (e.g., oceans, beaches, plains, and mountains) based on specified noise thresholds, `OCEAN_THRESHOLD`, `BEACH_THRESHOLD`, *et al.*
5. A fourth noise value is generated using only simplex noise with no scale adjustments; this noise value is then used to generate additional terrain detail (foreground colors and characters)

**EntryPoint.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TerrainGenerator.Terrain;
using CLIGL;

namespace TerrainGenerator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the entry point for the terrain generator as well as all
    /// requisite CLIGL initialization.
    /// </summary>
    public class EntryPoint
    {
        public const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 90;
        public const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 50;

        /// <summary>
        /// Entry point for the program.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command line arguments.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RenderingWindow window = new RenderingWindow("Terrain Generator", WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            RenderingBuffer buffer = new RenderingBuffer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

            Stopwatch timeAccumulator = new Stopwatch();
            timeAccumulator.Start();

            float previousElapsed = (float)timeAccumulator.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            float currentElapsed;
            float elapsedTime;
            float deltaTime;

            ChunkManager chunkManager = new ChunkManager(0, 0);
            while(true)
            {
                elapsedTime = (float)timeAccumulator.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                currentElapsed = elapsedTime;
                deltaTime = currentElapsed - previousElapsed;

                buffer.ClearPixelBuffer(RenderingPixel.EmptyPixel);
                chunkManager.Render(ref buffer);
                buffer.SetString(1, 1, $" T   = {elapsedTime.ToString("F2")} ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                buffer.SetString(1, 2, $" DT  = {deltaTime.ToString("F2")} ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                buffer.SetString(1, 3, $" FPS = {(1.0f / deltaTime).ToString("F2")} ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                buffer.SetString(1, 5, $" CMP  = ({chunkManager.Position.X}, {chunkManager.Position.Y}) ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                buffer.SetString(1, 6, $" CMCC = {chunkManager.ChunkCollection.Count} ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                buffer.SetString(1, 7, $" CMSD = {chunkManager.Seed} ", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                window.Render(buffer);

                chunkManager.Update();
                previousElapsed = currentElapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Position.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TerrainGenerator.Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a 2-dimensional position.
    /// </summary>
    public class Position
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Position class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">X-coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Y-coordinate.</param>
        public Position(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Translate the X and Y components (addition).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xOffset">The offset by which to translate X.</param>
        /// <param name="yOffset">The offset by which to translate Y.</param>
        public void Translate(int xOffset, int yOffset)
        {
            this.X += xOffset;
            this.Y += yOffset;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the hash code of the position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A hash code.</returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + this.X.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + this.Y.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for equality.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object with which to check for equality.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the passed object is equal to the current object.</returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Position))
            {
                Position cast = obj as Position;
                return
                    this.X == cast.X &&
                    this.Y == cast.Y;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Chunk.cs**

```
using System;
using TerrainGenerator.Utilities;
using CLIGL;

namespace TerrainGenerator.Terrain
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains all terrain data for a section of terrain (chunk). Instances of this 
    /// struct will be managed by the ChunkManager class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Chunk
    {
        public const int CHUNK_WIDTH = 16;
        public const int CHUNK_HEIGHT = 16;

        public const float NOISE_SCALE_A = 0.0015f;
        public const float NOISE_SCALE_B = 0.01f;
        public const float NOISE_SCALE_T = 0.1f;
        public const int NOISE_ITERATIONS = 4;
        public const float NOISE_PERSISTENCE = 0.6f;
        public const float NOISE_MULTIPLIER = 1.5f;

        public const float OCEAN_THRESHOLD = 0.0f;
        public const float BEACH_THRESHOLD = 0.1f;
        public const float PLAINS_THRESHOLD = 0.3f;
        public const float ALPINE_THRESHOLD = 0.4f;

        public Position Position { get; private set; }
        public RenderingPixel[,] Data { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Chunk struct.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The X position of the chunk.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The Y position of the chunk.</param>
        public Chunk(int x, int y)
        {
            this.Position = new Position(x, y);
            this.Data = new RenderingPixel[CHUNK_WIDTH, CHUNK_HEIGHT];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the Chunk struct.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"></param>
        public Chunk(Position position)
        {
            this.Position = position;
            this.Data = new RenderingPixel[CHUNK_WIDTH, CHUNK_HEIGHT];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate Chunk data with 3D perlin noise, given a specific seed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="seed"></param>
        public void GenerateData(int seed)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++)
                {
                    float noiseValueA = this.FractalNoise(this.Position.X + x + seed, this.Position.Y + y + seed, seed, NOISE_SCALE_A);
                    float noiseValueB = this.FractalNoise(this.Position.X + x + seed, this.Position.Y + y + seed, seed, NOISE_SCALE_B);
                    float noiseValueT = this.FractalNoise(this.Position.X + x + seed, this.Position.Y + y + seed, seed, NOISE_SCALE_T);
                    float terrainNoise = Lerp(noiseValueA, noiseValueB, (noiseValueT + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
                    float detailNoise = Noise.Generate(this.Position.X + x + seed, this.Position.Y + y + seed, seed);

                    (char, ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor) generatedTile = GenerateTile(terrainNoise, detailNoise);
                    this.Data[x, y] = new RenderingPixel(generatedTile.Item1, generatedTile.Item2, generatedTile.Item3);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render the generated tile data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="managerX">The X position of the chunk manager.</param>
        /// <param name="managerY">The Y position of the chunk manager.</param>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer to which the chunk is rendered.</param>
        public void RenderData(int managerX, int managerY, ref RenderingBuffer buffer)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++)
                {
                    buffer.SetPixel(this.Position.X + x - managerX, this.Position.Y + y - managerY, this.Data[x, y]);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a tile based on a given noise value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="terrainNoise">The noise value with which to generate terrain structure.</param>
        /// <param name="detailNoise">The nosie value with which to generate terrain detail.</param>
        /// <returns>A new tile.</returns>
        private static (char, ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor) GenerateTile(float terrainNoise, float detailNoise)
        {
            if(terrainNoise <= OCEAN_THRESHOLD)
            {
                char detailCharacter = GenerateDetailCharacter(detailNoise, 0.0f, 0.75f, ' ', '-', '~');    
                return (detailCharacter, ConsoleColor.Blue, ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            }

            else if(terrainNoise <= BEACH_THRESHOLD)
            {
                char detailCharacter = GenerateDetailCharacter(detailNoise, -0.25f, 0.75f, ' ', '.', '*');
                return (detailCharacter, ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            }

            else if(terrainNoise <= PLAINS_THRESHOLD)
            {
                char detailCharacter = GenerateDetailCharacter(detailNoise, -0.25f, 0.75f, ' ', '.', '*');
                return (detailCharacter, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            }

            else if(terrainNoise <= ALPINE_THRESHOLD)
            {
                char detailCharacter = GenerateDetailCharacter(detailNoise, 0.0f, 0.75f, ' ', '`', '.');
                return (detailCharacter, ConsoleColor.Gray, ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
            }

            else
            {
                char detailCharacter = GenerateDetailCharacter(detailNoise, 0.25f, 0.75f, ' ', '.', ',');
                return (detailCharacter, ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Gray);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a detail character.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="detailNoise">The noise value with which to generate detail.</param>
        /// <param name="threshold1">The first noise threshold for detail.</param>
        /// <param name="threshold2">The second noise threshold for additional detail.</param>
        /// <param name="char1">First detail character.</param>
        /// <param name="char2">Second detail character.</param>
        /// <param name="char3">Final detail character.</param>
        /// <returns>A detail character.</returns>
        public static char GenerateDetailCharacter(float detailNoise, float threshold1, float threshold2, char char1, char char2, char char3)
        {
            return detailNoise <= threshold1
                ? char1
                : detailNoise <= threshold2
                    ? char2
                    : char3;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a fractal noise value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The X position for which to generate noise.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The Y position for which to generate noise.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The Z position for which to generate noise.</param>
        /// <param name="frequency">Initial fractal noise frequency. Equivalent to scale.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This function assumes that a noise value has already been applied to 
        /// the position values.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A fractal noise value.</returns>
        private float FractalNoise(float x, float y, float z, float frequency)
        {
            float noise = 0.0f;
            float currentFrequency = frequency;
            float currentAmplitude = 1.0f;
            float maximumAmplitude = 0.0f;

            for(int i = 0; i < NOISE_ITERATIONS; i++)
            {
                noise += Noise.Generate(x * currentFrequency, y * currentFrequency, z * currentFrequency) * currentAmplitude;
                maximumAmplitude += currentAmplitude;
                currentAmplitude *= NOISE_PERSISTENCE;
                currentFrequency *= NOISE_MULTIPLIER;
            }

            return noise / maximumAmplitude;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Perform linear interpolation between two values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">The first value.</param>
        /// <param name="b">The second value.</param>
        /// <param name="t">The time value.</param>
        /// <returns>An interpolated value.</returns>
        private static float Lerp(float a, float b, float t)
        {
            return a + t * (b - a);
        }
    }
}
```

**ChunkManager.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TerrainGenerator.Utilities;
using CLIGL;

namespace TerrainGenerator.Terrain
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is responsible for storing and managing a collection of chunks. It
    /// will update the collection of chunks, deleting chunks and adding new chunks based
    /// on the current position of the manager.
    /// </summary>
    public class ChunkManager
    {
        public const int TRANSLATE_X = 2;
        public const int TRANSLATE_Y = 2;
        public const int CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_X = 6;
        public const int CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_Y = 3;
        public const int SEED_BOUNDS = 1000000;

        public int Seed { get; private set; }
        public Position Position { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<Position, Chunk> ChunkCollection { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the ChunkManager class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The X position of the manager.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y position of the manager.</param>
        public ChunkManager(int x, int y)
        {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            this.Seed = randomGenerator.Next(-SEED_BOUNDS, SEED_BOUNDS);
            this.Position = new Position(x, y);
            this.ChunkCollection = new Dictionary<Position, Chunk>(CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_X * CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_Y * 4);
            this.AddChunks();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render the contents of the chunk collection to a buffer.
        /// </summary>
        public void Render(ref RenderingBuffer buffer)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<Position, Chunk> chunk in this.ChunkCollection)
            {
                chunk.Value.RenderData(this.Position.X, this.Position.Y, ref buffer);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update the chunk manager; if no keys are pressed (and as a consequence, the
        /// position of the chunk manager remains unchanged), then AddChunks() and 
        /// DeleteChunks() are not called.
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            if(this.AdjustPosition())
            {
                this.DeleteChunks();
                this.AddChunks();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adjust the position of the chunk manager based on keyboard input.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Whether or not a key has been pressed.</returns>
        private bool AdjustPosition()
        {
            if(Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKey keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
                switch(keyPressed)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        this.Position.Translate(0, -TRANSLATE_Y);
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        this.Position.Translate(0, TRANSLATE_Y);
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        this.Position.Translate(-TRANSLATE_X, 0);
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        this.Position.Translate(TRANSLATE_X, 0);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If necessary (i.e., there is a chunk that should be loaded, but isn't), add a 
        /// new chunk into the current collection of chunks.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddChunks()
        {
            for(int y = -CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_Y; y <= CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_Y; y++)
            {
                for(int x = -CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_X; x <= CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_X; x++)
                {
                    int chunkX = this.Position.X + x * Chunk.CHUNK_WIDTH;
                    int chunkY = this.Position.Y + y * Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT;
                    int lockedChunkX = (int)(Math.Floor((decimal)chunkX / (decimal)Chunk.CHUNK_WIDTH) * (decimal)Chunk.CHUNK_WIDTH);
                    int lockedChunkY = (int)(Math.Floor((decimal)chunkY / (decimal)Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT) * (decimal)Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT);
                    Position position = new Position(lockedChunkX, lockedChunkY);

                    if(!this.ChunkCollection.ContainsKey(position))
                    {
                        this.ChunkCollection.Add(position, new Chunk(position));
                        this.ChunkCollection[position].GenerateData(this.Seed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If necessary (i.e., there is a chunk that is loaded, but shouldn't be), delete
        /// the chunk from the current collection of chunks.
        /// </summary>
        private void DeleteChunks()
        {
            List<Position> chunksToRemove = new List<Position>();
            foreach(KeyValuePair<Position, Chunk> chunk in this.ChunkCollection)
            {
                if(
                    Math.Abs(chunk.Value.Position.X - this.Position.X) > CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_X * Chunk.CHUNK_WIDTH * 2 ||
                    Math.Abs(chunk.Value.Position.Y - this.Position.Y) > CHUNK_LOADING_RANGE_Y * Chunk.CHUNK_HEIGHT * 2
                )
                {
                    chunksToRemove.Add(chunk.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach(Position position in chunksToRemove)
            {
                this.ChunkCollection.Remove(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With regards to review: I am primarily concerned with memory usage and performance (and if there exist any potential problems related to either of these issues); as of right now the generator uses at least 15% of my CPU across all processors and around 11 MB of memory, with memory usage increasing the longer the program runs, peaking at around 14 MB. That said, however, I welcome any other criticisms as well!

A few notes:

- The `Noise` class that I have used throughout this project is an implementation of the simplex noise algorithm in C# by Heikki Törmälä; the original source can be viewed [here](https://github.com/Xpktro/simplexnoise/blob/master/SimplexNoise/Noise.cs).
- This project links a previous project of mine, [CLIGL](https://github.com/Ethan-Bierlein/CLIGL); if you wish to test out this generator, you will need to download and compile CLIGL to a `.DLL` and link it accordingly.
- I *highly* recommend that, should you wish to test this project for yourself, that you set the font of your console window to a raster font with a size of `12x16`.
- For those who may not wish to go to the effort of downloading and compiling CLIGL and this project, I have uploaded a video demonstrating the generator [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P41fpKucUs).

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using chunks? It looks like each pixel can be updated individually... so we could use a single toroidal buffer, and update only the exact pixels that need it due to movement (i.e. a strip along the side of our window for movement in one direction, or an L-shape for movement in two).

Comment: @user673679 You’re definitely right in that regard; a toroidal buffer would have been a more apt solution for this problem. I did initially try to implement something to that effect, but I could not, for the life of me, get it to work; I’ve done a pretty significant amount of work with video engines in the past, and I am used to a chunk-based model, so I stuck with that.

Comment: Position and Chunck classes,  could possibly merged. as Position is a struct and not a class for current configuration. Also, consider moving all constants to its own `static class`, for easier maintainability, and also to ensure you'll have only one instance of them. You can also wrap everything under meaningful name ( for user-experience), it would be possible to achieve something like `var tg = new TerrainGenerator()` and then, everything I need would be accessible in `TerrainGenerator` This also will act as publish layer where you'll expose/hide what you need for the user (developer).

Comment: @iSR5 please don't answer in comments. Write an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from top to bottom.

`EntryPoint`

```
Stopwatch timeAccumulator = new Stopwatch();
timeAccumulator.Start();
```

can be simplified by using `var` instead of the concrete type and by using the [`static Stopwatch Stopwatch.StartNew()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Stopwatch_StartNew) method.

`Position`

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Position))
    {
        Position cast = obj as Position;
        return
            this.X == cast.X &&
            this.Y == cast.Y;
    }

    return false;
}
```

can be simplified like so

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Position cast)
    {
        return
            this.X == cast.X &&
            this.Y == cast.Y;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You don't check wether `x` or `y` is in a valid range. I don't know if your code get problems if either of this will be negative. If yes you should check these parameters in your constructor and add validation for the property-setter as well.

`Chunk`

```
public Chunk(int x, int y)
{
    this.Position = new Position(x, y);
    this.Data = new RenderingPixel[CHUNK_WIDTH, CHUNK_HEIGHT];
}
```

can be simplified by using constructor chaining like so

```
public Chunk(int x, int y) : this(new Position(x, y))
{}
```

`ChunkManager`

In `AdjustPosition()` and other methods you should place a guarding clause to return early. This saves one indentation level for the whole method like so

```
private bool AdjustPosition()
{
    if(!Console.KeyAvailable) { return false; }

    ConsoleKey keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
    switch(keyPressed)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            this.Position.Translate(0, -TRANSLATE_Y);
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            this.Position.Translate(0, TRANSLATE_Y);
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
            this.Position.Translate(-TRANSLATE_X, 0);
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
            this.Position.Translate(TRANSLATE_X, 0);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and by adding the `ConsoleKey`'s and `Action<int, int>` to a dictionary you can replace the `switch` completely.

`General`

The usage of `this` adds only noise to your code. Just use it only if you really need to use it.

Comment: I could make the `Equals` method even shorter: `return obj is Point other && X == other.X && Y == other.Y;` -- is that an idiomatic way to write an Equals method?

Comment: @RolandIllig good point. Make it into an answer and get my +1 and if your answer is the only one except mine yiu will earn the bounty as well.